# How do we flag an inappropriate avatar?

Tags: discussion, flags, etiquette, gravatar

There is a user (whose initial post/rant caused quite a stir in the past 24 hours and it had appeared as if the user was deleted for a while) who has an avatar in which the "F" bomb is dropped. The text is small and you wouldn't really be able to read the avatar unless you were to visit the user's profile.

Should this be flagged for mod attention? If so, should the flag just be placed on a post by that user with a note for the mod?

Comment: If you find a gravatar offensive, then you can go to any of their posts and use a custom moderator flag explaining the issue.

Comment: Yeah, that guy. I had removed one of their previous accounts and rolled back the avatar on another of them. I did the same here, but if he steps out of line and starts insulting people again, don't hesitate to flag and we'll take more serious measures to prevent further problems.