# Why was my flag on an inapproriate username declined?

Tags: support, flags, declined-flags, display-names, custom-flags

I flagged [an otherwise valid post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67082153/pygame-installed-on-windows-getting-pygame-error-failed-loading-libwebp-7-dll) that was posted by a [user with an f-bomb in their name](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7429291) (brainf*** best language).  While it was referring to the brainf*** language, it still isn't allowed.  This is a clear instance of an offensive username.

Quoting [this answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251684/8384089) by a moderator:

> Pick out a post by that user (any answer or question will do) and flag it for moderator attention. Pick the 'other' option and explain that you find the username to be offensive.

> A moderator will look into it and, if necessary, rename the account.

Which is exactly what I did.  However it got declined:

[image: Declined flag against user with f-bomb in their name]

Does this mean that f-bombs are allowed on Stack Overflow?  [That was not the impression I was getting](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/287817/8384089).  Why was this flag declined?

Comment: Brainfuck is the name of a language. Therefore, this is not an offensive user name, it does not violate our Code of Conduct, and it did not need to be reset. End of story. There is no need for any additional comments or discussion here. The original comments have been [archived in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/234791/discussion-on-question-by-anonymous-why-was-my-flag-on-an-inapproriate-username).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You flagged a borderline case of potentially objectionable content on Stack Overflow. A moderator reviewed your claim, but disagreed. That's where the story ends here.

I *do* think you were well within your right to flag this, but you must recognize that a moderator is also well within *their* right to disagree with you, and they get the final say here. Per moderator [Cody Gray](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/366904/cody-gray) above, the fact that this term is the name of a real programming language qualifies it as not running afoul of the code of conduct or content policy, even though it contains a term that would otherwise qualify it for removal.

Regarding your final question:

> Does this mean that f-bombs are allowed on Stack Overflow?

[No.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22232/are-expletives-cursing-swear-words-or-vulgar-language-allowed-on-se-sites/22233#22233)

It's simply an *exception* to the rule, which [moderators exist to control for](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/05/18/a-theory-of-moderation/#:%7E:text=Moderators%20are%20human%20exception%20handlers).

Comment: Yes, of course; please do not take my comment to imply that one is not within their rights to raise a flag in a case like this, or, indeed, any case where one sees something that makes them uncomfortable. The "declined" status on a flag just means that a moderator *declined* to take action in the flagged case. It does not necessarily mean that the flag was completely bogus. All the comment here meant to imply that we don't need to have a protracted discussion in the comments about myopic and tangential issues...